# Register factory class in Autofac using web.config

Tags: configuration, autofac

I have been looking for a way to register a factory class in autofac using [XmlConfiguration](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/XmlConfiguration) but the documentation seems a bit slim.

What I want to accomplish is to do the following in my configuration instead:

`builder.Register(c => MyFactory.GetMyObject()).As<IMyObject>();`

Are there any good way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to do this is to encapsulate your registration into an Autofac Module, which can be registered from XML. (Modules are described here: http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/StructuringWithModules)

Your module would look something like:

```
public class MyModule : Module
{
  protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
  {
    builder.Register(c => MyFactory.GetMyObject()).As<IMyObject>();
  }
}
```

And the XML to register it:

```
<module type="MyModule" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Autofac was originally built to be configured, even autowired, from code.

Perhaps what you're looking for is something like [Spring.NET](http://www.springframework.net/) or [Castle](http://www.castleproject.org/). These two frameworks were originally built to be configured, even autowired, from XML.

Answer (score 0):

Handling registration from code seem to have some advantages to using web.config since it seems easier to handle complex dependencies this way.

The only concern I had when following the examples i could find was that all the registration was done in Global.asax. This is quite easy to fix by breaking out the registration to a separate Assembly though.